# Unlabeled ODBC connection string

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I have a task that needs me to ETL from an ODBC MSSQL server. All I have is this string.

"66.239.210.201\MSSQLSERVER,1488"

This is the IP, db name, and port, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That string is IP address, Instance and Port (not DB name) Here's a good reference https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

(BTW afaik, the instance name is ignored when you specify the port number)